# Chinese text are not coming in PDF created using kendo-react-pdf

Tags: reactjs, pdf, kendo-react-ui

I am using @progress/kendo-react-pdf for exporting PDF in my react application.
I have defined @font-face with truetype format as described in kendo-react-pdf documentations but there is no success.

The exported PDF with chinese character comes with squares as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can using 'kendo.pdf.defineFont()'

the font must be available on the server and properly declared in CSS, or embedded via font packing utility.

and maybe you can see this link : https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/4579